# How to tell when Mkannotations are pressed swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

Hey guys i'm really stuck and I have not found an answer for this anywhere , so here we go.

I have a mapView that needs to display multiple mkannotations so I make an array and store there title , sub title etc from a array of "posts" which were users posts that were shared to the map (this code works fine)

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
var posts = [Post]() // arr of local post objects

  func addPostsToMap(){
    mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    annotations.removeAll()
    for post in posts{
        let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(post.lat, post.lon)
        let annotation = PostAnnotation(title: post.userName , subtitle: post.postContent, coordinate: location)
        annotations.append(annotation)
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)

}
```

here is the custom postAnnotation :

```
class PostAnnotation : NSObject , MKAnnotation{

var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title : String , subtitle : String , coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}



}
```

**Issue** how do i tell which annotation is pressed?? I have found i can deque a custom annotation with a mapkit delegate method , however there is no "indexPath" like a table view , so how am i suppost to tell which one is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra field to your `PostAnnotation` that is the index of the post in the `posts` array.

Then in your implementation of `mapView(MKMapView, didSelect: MKAnnotationView)` you just need to get the annotation for the view that was tapped, then use the index to get the post from the array.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    guard let postAnnotation = view.annotation as? PostAnnotation else {
        return
    }

    let post = posts[postAnnotation.index]
    // do something with post
}
```